# Spring boot profile not picking the properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have `application-database.yml`, `application-sql.yml`.Tried running using `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` but  properties data not picking up. How to run this?

application-local.yml

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      local: database, sql, message
  application: 
    name: HP-FETCHER-CONFIG-SERVICE
```

Comment: AFAIK Spring Boot loads `.yml` files and not `.yaml` files. Try changing the extension.

Comment: Is there any properties to activate profile group or only way to activate like this -Dspring.profile.active=groupname

Answer (score 0):

by `Dspring.profiles.active=local`  you are telling spring that you use `local` profile, use `Dspring.profiles.active=database` instead

Comment: That is not what OP is trying to accomplish. He want to activate all three profiles.

Comment: Yes want to activate all profile but it mentioned in application.local

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies to your project：

just use application.yml，then：

```
spring:                                                                                                                                                                                                
  profiles:                                                                     
    active: local, database, sql

---                                                                                                                
spring:                                                                                                            
  profiles: local1
  ...
...

---                                                                                                                
spring:                                                                                                            
  profiles: local
  ...
...

---                                                                                                                
spring:                                                                                                            
  profiles: sql
  ...
...

---                                                                                                                
spring:                                                                                                            
  profiles: database
  ...
...
```

when start without `-Dspring.profiles.active` it will use the `local, database, sql`. if start with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local1,database,sql` it will use the `local1, database, sql`

Comment: Is there any properties to activate profile group or only way to activate like this -Dspring.profile.active=groupname

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `group` you have to specify it in either `application.yml` or `application.properties` file. The corresponding [blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) says:

*To define a group, you can use the spring.profiles.group property in your application.properties or application.yml file.*

Comment: Can't activate group value in any another way?

Answer (score 0):

For me this seems to be working as expected. I have the below `application.yml` file

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      super-1-2: profile-1, profile-2
      super-2-3: profile-2, profile-3

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
      - profile-1
      
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
      - profile-2

---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
      - profile-3
```

If I run my application with profile `super-1-2` activated, I get a confirmation in my logs that all three `super-1-2`, `profile-1` and `profile-2` are active.

```
2022-08-31 16:52:27.109  INFO 67935 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.n.SampleApplication      : The following 3 profiles are active: "super-1-2", "profile-1", "profile-2"
```

On the other hand, if I run my application with profile `super-2-3` activated, I get a confirmation in my logs that all three `super-2-3`, `profile-2`, and `profile-3` are active.

```
2022-08-31 16:52:41.117  INFO 68090 --- [  restartedMain] c.s.n.SampleApplication      : The following 3 profiles are active: "super-2-3", "profile-2", "profile-3"
```

Comment: The group list can either be comma separated values or `yml` representation of a list.

Comment: But I mentioned in application-local.its any way to activate all profile group when local active

Comment: I believe you will have to define the groups at the application.yml level rather than at profile-specific application-xxx.yml. I have updated my answer based on multiple definitions. Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any properties to activate profile group or only way to activate like this -Dspring.profile.active=groupname

Comment: Is there any properties to activate profile group or only way to activate like this -Dspring.profile.active=groupname  @Dishant kamble

Comment: I believe you can simply activate a profile by defining an environment variable. Spring understands environment variables like spring.profile.active = groupname is can be comprehended by Spring with an environment variable name SPRING_PROFILE_ACTIVE=groupname. So thats another way to activate i believe.